# Problem using wget to download an entire website

Tags: downloads, wget

As said in `wget` man page:

> to download a single page and all its requisites (even if they exist on separate websites), and make sure the lot displays properly locally, this author likes to use a few options in addition to -p:
>
> wget -E -H -k -K -p http://mysite.com/directory

I understand, if I want to download mysite entirely, I have to add `-r` argument. But using both `-r` and `-H` options yields downloading all the website reachable from http://mysite.com/directory. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `wget`, you can use the mirror setting to make an offline copy of a website, although some websites might prevent it with their robots.txt settings that stops automated spidering. I have always had a few problems with `wget` (see my other suggestion below), but the following command does work for many sites. However, be **aware** that the addition of the `-H` switch allows it to access all links that are on other sites and to save those also. This command switch can obviously be removed if it is not required.

```
 wget --wait 1 -x -H -mk http://site.to.mirror/
```

The command to `wait` allows some gaps between `wget's` requests so that the site is not overwhelmed, and the `-x` command switch specifies that the site's directory structure should be exactly mirrored in a folder in your home folder. The `-m` switch obviously stands for mirror mode, which allows `wget` to download recursively through the site; and the `-k` switch means that after download the files referenced will be those in your mirror directory in your home folder and not those back at the site itself.

After `man wget`, perhaps the best listing and detailed explanation of `wget` commands is [here](http://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/wget-download-manager/).

If `wget` is unsuccessful and you can't grab as much as you want, I should try the command line program `httrack` or its web interface, `webhttrack`, which are available in the repositories. There are a large amount of options for this program, but it is better for downloading whole websites or parts of websites than `wget`. `Webhttrack` gives you a wizard to follow for downloading a site (it opens in your browser) as the screenshot below shows.

[image: Httrack]

Comment: -x -mk does not work when the page requisites is in a separate site.

Comment: I have edited my wget command by adding the -H switch which will fetch the external links. Try httrack if you can't get wget to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a while since I used `wget` for this purpose:

I believe I had success with the `- m` flag.

```
wget -mk http://site.com/directory
```

This probably won't get everything - but it will get you close.

(Reference): [This page](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/)

Comment: -m does not work when the page requisites is in a separate site.